# Adding the attribute 'selected' to Checkbox in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

I am using `<Checkbox>` component in my react project. The code is

App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Checkbox from '../../../components/Checkbox/Checkbox.jsx';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div style={{ 'float': 'left', 'background': 'white' }}><Checkbox
             input={{
             name: 'sampleName',
             onChange: (e) => this.onSelect(e.target.checked),
             value: allSelected
             }}
          /></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}



export default connect(

)(App);
```

Checkbox.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

import './Checkbox.scss';

class Checkbox extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { input: {name, size, value, onChange}, disabled } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="checkbox">
                <input disabled={disabled} id={name} type="checkbox" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
                <label htmlFor={name} className={size}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Checkbox;
```

I want to include one more attribute `checked: {Item.Selected}` to the `<Checkbox>` tag , for that what changes I needed to make in the Checkbox.jsx page to accepet the value of the attribute `selected`?

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" checked={this.props.checked} .../>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if understanding this correctly, but if I do. 
App.jsx

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Checkbox
             input={{
             name: 'sampleName',
             onChange: (e) => this.onSelect(e.target.checked),
             value: allSelected
             }}
             checked={(your condition, evaluating to true/false)}
             disabled={whatever}                                
          />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And then
Checkbox.jsx

```
class Checkbox extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { input: {name, size, value, onChange}, disabled, checked } = this.props;
    return (
        <div className="checkbox">
            <input disabled={disabled} checked={checked} id={name} type="checkbox" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
            <label htmlFor={name} className={size}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are calling attribute, is called prop in react. When you pass a prop to a component, you can get it with `this.props` in that component. So, your files should be like these:

App.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Checkbox from '../../../components/Checkbox/Checkbox.jsx';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div style={{ 'float': 'left', 'background': 'white' }}><Checkbox
             checked={Item.Selected}
             input={{
             name: 'sampleName',
             onChange: (e) => this.onSelect(e.target.checked),
             value: allSelected
             }}
          /></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}



export default connect(

)(App);
```

Checkbox.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

import './Checkbox.scss';

class Checkbox extends React.Component {
    render() {
        //the checked variable added below:
        const { input: {name, size, value, onChange}, disabled, checked } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="checkbox">
                <input disabled={disabled} id={name} type="checkbox" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
                <label htmlFor={name} className={size}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Checkbox;
```